# Is there an equvalent to Dim/var in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and i have a case where vb.nets Dim or C#s var would help me greatly.

i googled around and i found no questions for this? (although search terms with var or dim and C++ seemed to stray easy)

is there an equivalent for this?

Comment: Vague question. Dimensioning a variable has a lot of behaviors. Found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1(v=vs.80).aspx Which (sub)set are you looking for ? Are you looking for variables without types ? Something with access modifiers ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in the current standard.

However, the new version that is probably due this year (most likely called C++11, but it's also still often referred to as C++0x) has `auto` that does that same thing as `var`.
It's already supported by recent versions of [all big compilers](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport).

For example:

```
auto MyValue = SomeFunction(); // The compiler will figure out the type of MyValue
```

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for the [`auto` keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Type_inference) in C++0x.

Answer (score 4):

As per my comment, Dim does a lot of different things.

If you are looking for a variable that can be anything, or something that will work like

```
Dim var
var = 1
var = "Hello"
Set var = new Thing
```

You can use

1. void* and cast
2. a union type of all the possible thing this variable can be, if these are known in advance
3. boost::variant<> - discriminated union, also if all types are known in advance
4. boost::any - any type you want, the closest I can think of to Dim

Cliff notes:

boost::any will work for you

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can use `union`s or use a base class and inheritance.

The `union` allows you to have an area in memory and organize it in different ways.  A base class and inheritance allows you to treat child objects in a common manner.

```
union
{
  int value;
  double floating_point;
};
```

In the `union` above, the integer `value` and the double precision `floating_point` variables occupy the same area (*within the union*).

The `union` may be the closest data structure to a variant record.  The Boost library also has a *variant* data structure, search the web for "boost variant".